# Plot many csv files in one window

Tags: r, csv, plot, time-series

I have a list of 701 given `csv` files. Each one has the same number of columns (7) but different number of rows (between 25000 and 28000).

Here is an extract of the first file:

```
Date,Week,Week Day,Hour,Price,Volume,Sale/Purchase
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-3000.00,17416,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1001.10,17427,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1000.00,18055,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.10,18057,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.00,18064,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.10,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.00,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.10,18068,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.00,18118,Sell
```

Now I am trying to plot `Volume` and `Date` on condition that the `Price` is exactly `200.00`. And then I am trying to get one window where I can see the progress of the Volume over the time.

```
allenamen <- dir(pattern="*.csv")
alledat <- lapply(allenamen, read.csv, header = TRUE, 
   sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
verlauf <- function(a) {plot(Volume ~ Date, a, 
  data=subset(a, (Price=="200.00")), 
  ylim = c(15000, 45000), 
  xlim = as.Date(c("2011-12-30", "2013-01-20")), type = "l")}
lapply(alledat, verlauf)
```

But I get this error:

```
error in strsplit(log, NULL): non-character argument
```

How can I avoid the error?

Comment: There is no `strsplit` in your code

Comment: What `class` is your `Date` column?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know that there is no strsplit in my code but why do I get the error then?

Comment: @beginneR class(alledat$Date) says "NULL"

Comment: @fYpsE you should probably convert it to a proper `Date` format then before plotting. try for example `alledat$Date <- as.Date(alledat$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: @beginneR I get the error in as.Date.default(alledat$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y") : does not know how to transform 'alledat$Date' in class “Date”. I hope you understand my translation.

Comment: Then try `alledat$Date <- as.Date(as.character(alledat$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")` - does that work?

Comment: I get still the error: error in strsplit(log, NULL): non-character argument

Comment: Just one more thing you may want to change: if your `Price` column is `numeric` you can write `Price == 200.00` instead of `Price=="200.00"`. If it's not numeric, you may also want to change that. Plus you can remove the parenthesis around `Price== 200.00` inside the `subset`

Comment: 2 comments ... a) in your verlauf function right after the formula you have a parameter "a", and then you specify "data = subset(...)". How about removing paramenter "a"?  b) if you have 701 csv's, and you use lapply, all of them will be plot , remove, plot, remove so you will only be able to see the last of the graph corresponding to the last of your 701 csv files on screen. Maybe you should add to your code pdf() and dev.off() so output is sent to a pdf than can later be reviewed.

Comment: @luis I removed the parameter a and there was no error message. But the x-axis displays 15400 till 15700 and the plot is empty.

And in the end I want to display all the points in just one plot. So I do not want 701 different plots. Does that work?

Comment: You need to take a step back.  Create a **small** dummy array `alledat` and verify its contents are of the desired types (numeric, char, etc).  Then verify your `subset` call extracts the correct set of data,  then plot that data.  This will help you understand what your code needs to look like, as well as helping locate errors.

Comment: @Carl I tried the code with just one csv file and it worked perfectly. The errors appear when using lapply().

Comment: Fyi, `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` are both unnecessary in read.csv as they are both defaults.

Comment: What platform are you running?  This is extremely easy in a shell or terminal, to create a file to send to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to combine all subsets for `Price==200` into one plot, you can use the following function:

```
plotprice <- function(x) {
  files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    xx <- read.csv(as.character(files[i]))
    xx <- subset(xx, Price==x)
    df <- rbind(df, xx)
  }
  df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
  plot(Volume ~ Date, df, ylim = c(15000, 45000), xlim = as.Date(c("2011-12-30", "2013-01-20")), type = "l")
}
```

With `plotprice(200)` you will everything in one plot for `Price==200`.

---

When you want a plot for each `csv` file, you can use:

```
ploteach <- function(x) {
  files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    df <- read.csv(as.character(files[i]))
    df <- subset(df, Price==x)
    df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
    plot(Volume ~ Date, df, ylim = c(15000, 45000), xlim = as.Date(c("2011-12-30", "2013-01-20")), type = "l")
  }
}

ploteach(200)
```

Comment: The code works. Thank you very much. There is just one thing. If I add in the subset part "df <- subset(df, Price ==x, Hour == 9, Sale.Purchase == "Sell") I get the error that R can not find Sale.Purchase. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @fYpsE In your question you defined the variable as `Sale/Purchase` instead of `Sale.Purchase`. That probably causes the error.

Comment: With head() the column is called Sale.Purchase, so I have to use Sale.Purchase. But indifferent the code works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

1. Use `list.files`, not `dir`, to find files.  `dir` is used to list the files in a directory. The way you are using it is for the current directory.
2. `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` are default arguments for `read.csv`, and therefore unnecessary in your code.
3. Subset each file as it's read

Here's a suggested method.

```
> fnames <- list.files(pattern  = "*.csv")
> read <- lapply(fnames, function(x){
    rd <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    subset(rd, Price == 200)
    })
> dat <- do.call(rbind, read)
```

And you should then be able to plot `dat`.

Comment: I get the error: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : generate NAs by transformation

Comment: I am sorry but I can not make two green ticks. I hope this is not a problem for you.

Comment: @fYpsE, it's no big deal.  If both the solutions worked, now you have options for future projects!

Comment: @RichardScriven a +1 for another nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you need to transform the result of your lapply - read.csv from a list of 701 csv's to a single data frame.

Added function to read and subset, to avoid running out of RAM:

```
#
# function to read and subset data to avoid running out of RAM
read.subset <- function(dateiname){
   a <- read.csv(file = dateiname, header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   a <- a[a$Price == 200.00,]
   print(gc())    # monitor and clean RAM after each file is read
   return(a)
}
```

*** Update 2: Added a faster implementation of read.subset using scan

```
# function to read and subset data to avoid running out of RAM
read.subset.fast <- function(dateiname){
   # get data from csv into a data.frame
   a <- scan(file          = dateiname,
             what          = c(list(character()),
                               rep(list(numeric()),5),
                               list(character())),
             skip          = 1,  # skip header (equivalent to header = TRUE)
             sep           = ",")
   # transform efficiently list into data.frame
   attributes(a) <- list(class      = "data.frame",
                         row.names  = c(NA_integer_, length(a[[1]])),
                         names      = scan(file          = dateiname,
                                           what          = character(),
                                           skip          = 0,  
                                           nlines        = 1,  # just read first line to extract column names
                                           sep           = ","))
   # subset data
   a <- a[a$Price == 200.00,]
   print(gc())
   return(a)
}
#
```

Now let's read, subset and combine data in a single data frame:

```
#
allenamen <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") # updated (@Richard Scriven)
# get a single data frame, instead of a list of 701 data frames
alledat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(allenamen, read.subset.fast))
#
```

Transform date in to the right format:

```
# get dates in dates format
alledat$Date <- as.Date(as.character(alledat$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then you are good to go, no function needed. Just plot it:

```
plot(Volume ~ Date, 
     data = alledat,
     ylim = range(Volume),
     xlim = range(Date),
     type = "l")
```

Comment: That is a great idea but I have one problem. If I try to rbind the files to one data frame, my Computer needs 10 minutes to calculate and in the end I get this error: In rbind(deparse.level, ...) : Reached total allocation of 4043Mb: see help(memory.size). The files are too big to do this. Is there a possibility to filter just the rows with Price == 200.00 before the rbind command?

Comment: Yeap, added function read.subset to do the job. Does this solution answer your question now?

Comment: `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","` are both unnecessary in `read.csv` as they are both defaults.

Comment: I get a warning after alledat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(allenamen, read.subset.fast)): error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : scan() expected 'a real', got '3B'. If I continue with alledat$Date <- as.Date(as.character(alledat$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y") R says he can not find object 'alledat'.

Comment: I tested read.subset.fast with the dataset you provided, and it works fine. There must be some not standard data in any of your .csv. So try with read.subset function, instead of read.subset.fast and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: You could also type this command and add the output to your question: dput(head(read.csv(allenamen[1]),50))  This will read a csv and extract the code to reproduce the first 50 lines of the object read.

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L,...,1L), .Label = "18/03/2011", class = "factor"), 
    Week = c(11L,...,11L), Week.Day = c(5L,...,5L), 
    Hour = c(1L,...,1L), Price = c(-3000, -1001.1, 
    -1000,...,-0.01, 
    0), Volume = c(17416L,...,18367L), Sale.Purchase = structure(c(2L,...,2L), .Label = c("Purchase", "Sell"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Week", "Week.Day", "Hour", "Price", "Volume", "Sale.Purchase"
), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: This was the output of the dput command.
The same warning appears with read.subset.

Comment: I'm sorry, this debugging process is going no where.